# data-explorer - wrong user-id

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, user-accounts

This I came across visiting the data explorer. It's not quite restricted to it, though.

Whenever I load up a query, the value in `UserId` textbox is 255753, whereas mine is actually 255756.

255753 is an unregistered user which has been last seen 2 minutes before I actually signed up. Even the gravatars are the same.

Comment: For some reason, you have the same email hash as well (presumably why you have the same Gravatar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field value is "guessed" by trying to match your SEDE e-mail hash to a user's e-mail hash from the selected site's data set:

```
select top 1 Id from Users where EmailHash = @EmailHash
```

Looking at the [two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255753/goresplatter) [gravatars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255756/linus-kleen), it appears you accidentally created an extra account -- the unregistered one has a lower Id value, so it comes up before your real account.

---

Please follow the [appropriate instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste) to merge your accounts together (cleaner).

I [have added](http://code.google.com/r/jseigelis-test/source/detail?r=a506024c74802821a509a561d541cdcd225a1132) an ordering clause to the query so if there are multiple accounts with the same e-mail hash, the one with the highest reputation will populate the text box.